# Sending and getting cookie to/from server in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, authentication, nsurlsession

I'm making an iOS-app in Swift which requeries login, and i got a server that checks if the cookie that is set when a login is correct, is the same that the server got, everytime i call the server.

I need help sending the cookie to my server (its user information like email and password). And every time i call the server the cookie must be send. The server doesnt validates the user info (execpt when logging in), it just check if the cookie value is correct.

I've been looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596206/how-to-get-cookie-from-a-nsurlsession-with-swift) thread in order to find an answer to my issue, and it works to set a cookie for my session.

**But how do i send the cookie to my server and how do i check if the cookie that's set when login is the same that the server got?**