# How get value of headers in request (URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error)

Tags: ios, swift, httpresponse, nsurlsession

I need to get value of Header "Set-Cookie" - sessid = EZEaqDixCNZKjY4HwEXSjuR8lKhqkHXGLX6SoZSmtdUegKP7AkUuFOpUIHygf3M5

Now I can get all string, but I need only value for sessid - EZEaqDixCNZKjY4HwEXSjuR8lKhqkHXGLX6SoZSmtdUegKP7AkUuFOpUIHygf3M5

How can I pars this String or give me advise how to get this property.

[image: Case]

Comment: [The right answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596206/how-to-get-cookie-from-a-nsurlsession-with-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"sessid=EZEaqDixCNZKjY4HwEXSjuR8lKhqkHXGLX6SoZSmtdUegKP7AkUuFOpUIHygf3M5;".replacingOccurrences(of: "sessid=", with: "").dropLast()
// Result: EZEaqDixCNZKjY4HwEXSjuR8lKhqkHXGLX6SoZSmtdUegKP7AkUuFOpUIHygf3M5
```

First we remove `"sessid="` and then dropping the semicolon.

Comment: all string look like this `sessid=ETLqmdsPiBEfjw008XxEZNUvLpNif6sNC7ABF3jmepfduzhRPljzszx20af8PJtn; path=/, CurrentCulture=ru; path=/`

Comment: `"sessid=ETLqmdsPiBEfjw008XxEZNUvLpNif6sNC7ABF3jmepfduzhRPljzszx20af8PJtn; path=/, CurrentCulture=ru; path=/".split(separator: ";").first?.replacingOccurrences(of: "sessid=", with: "")` One more step added - splitting string by semicolon and no more need in dropping last character

Comment: It's solve my problem, but maybe there is a method to pars Headers in response? Thank you any way

Comment: If you're asking about header parsing methods from `Foundation` framework, then i believe there is no. It's users responsibility to parse header values.